# Is there any fast way to convert List<byte> to hex string?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

i have a List, i need to convert it to  hex strings. i feel like the way i am converting is quiet long.

```
List<byte> TRIGGER_POL = Data.GetRange(23, 1);
byte[] TRIGGER_POL_temp = new byte[TRIGGER_POL.Count];
TRIGGER_POL_temp[0] = TRIGGER_POL[0];
string TRIGGER_POL_hx = BitConverter.ToString(TRIGGER_POL_temp, 0).Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

is there a faster, efficient way to do this?

Thanks..

Comment: Don't know if it's faster, but generally when you want to convert a byte-array to a string you use Encoding.<preffered encoding>.GetString.

Comment: So you want the whole array as 1 string or just the bytes to a list of strings (eg: byte(233) = "233")

Comment: @sa_ddam213, i need to convert to list byte array to hex strings. sorry i forgot to mention before the conversion to hex strings. ex:  `T[255 0] = 0xF0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are losts of ways to do this but this one may work for you

```
 List<string> hexStrings = TRIGGER_POL.Select(b => BitConverter.ToString(new byte[]{b})).ToList();
```

or if you want just 1 string

```
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(TRIGGER_POL.ToArray());
```

Comment: the second conversion `TRIGGER_POL.ToArray()` works great and reduces number of lines.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

My personal favorate way of doing this is a little known class buried deep within .NET [SoapHexBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.metadata.w3cxsd2001.soaphexbinary.aspx)

```
byte[] tmp1 = SoapHexBinary.Parse("DEADBEEF"); //tmp1 now equals the array {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF}
string tmp2 = new SoapHexBinary(tmp1).ToString(); //tmp2 now equals "DEADBEEF"
```

Comment: thanks i didnt know abt this class..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static string ConvertToHex(byte[] bytes)
{
    SoapHexBinary hexBin = new SoapHexBinary(bytes);
    return hexBin.ToString();
}
return ConvertToHex(TRIGGER_POL.ToArray());
```